# How to Migrate Ubuntu 12.04 installation to another partition in simple way?

Tags: 12.04

I've installed 12.04 to run alongside my Windows7 but in the process a couple of things happened.

1. my install went wrong and I wound up with an extra partition.  It was compromised so I've wiped it and formatted ext4 to match my current 12.04 install.
2. my working 12.04 partition is in a very large partition that I want to use as a media partition to be accessed by either OS.

I want to migrate the contents of my current partition to the newly formatted ext4 partition, reformat the bigger partition to ntfs (I am a big fan of the 'search everything' application on Win7) and somehow set Ubuntu to mount my soon-to-be-new media partition on startup.

I notice a 'linux swap' partition.  I have no idea what that is and I presume it's for the system to constantly be reorganizing itself and probably have to deal with that as well as getting the bootloader to recognize the migrated partition.

I will admit that I have no idea how to decipher code for the terminal and prefer for a program/application to be working the code through the system for me.  That being said, dragging and dropping lines of code into the terminal isn't beyond me.

What's the simplest, most straight forward way to do this?

[image: screenshot1]

edit to add:  my apologies for an otherwise bloated entry...It was suggested to me to provide system details and I have.  If there's a better way to do this please advise.
.r.

[image: Filesystemz]

```
Mounted File Systems
/dev/sda7   /   12.95 % (260.8 GiB of 299.6 GiB)
udev    /dev    0.00 % (2.9 GiB of 2.9 GiB)
tmpfs   /run    0.07 % (1.2 GiB of 1.2 GiB)
none    /run/lock   0.00 % (5.0 MiB of 5.0 MiB)
none    /run/shm    0.11 % (2.9 GiB of 2.9 GiB)


Computer

Summary
Computer
Processor   4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory  6060MB (1599MB used)
Operating System    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
User Name   newboldrob (Rob Newbold)
Date/Time   Thu 17 May 2012 02:51:12 PM EDT
Display
Resolution  1366x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer Unknown
X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Multimedia
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
Input Devices
Power Button    
Lid Switch  
Power Button    
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard    
Toshiba input device    
CNF9055 
Video Bus   
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad  
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm   3=
Printers
No printers found   
SCSI Disks
ATA Seagate ST950056    
MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8A0AS    
Generic- xD/SD/M.S. 
Operating System
Version
Kernel  Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
Distribution    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Current Session
Computer Name   Satellite-E305
User Name   newboldrob (Rob Newbold)
Home Directory  /home/newboldrob
Desktop Environment Unity (ubuntu)
Misc
Uptime  19 minutes
Load Average    1.04, 0.89, 0.61
Kernel Modules
Loaded Modules
snd_hda_codec_hdmi  HDMI HD-audio codec
joydev  Joystick device interfaces
rfcomm  Bluetooth RFCOMM ver 1.11
bnep    Bluetooth BNEP ver 1.3
bluetooth   Bluetooth Core ver 2.16
parport_pc  PC-style parallel port driver
ppdev   
snd_hda_intel   Intel HDA driver
snd_hda_codec   HDA codec core
snd_hwdep   Hardware dependent layer
snd_pcm Midlevel PCM code for ALSA.
arc4    ARC4 Cipher Algorithm
snd_seq_midi    Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer MIDI synth.
snd_rawmidi Midlevel RawMidi code for ALSA.
snd_seq_midi_event  MIDI byte <-> sequencer event coder
snd_seq Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer.
snd_timer   ALSA timer interface
snd_seq_device  ALSA sequencer device management
psmouse PS/2 mouse driver
rts_pstor   Realtek PCI-Express card reader driver
iwlwifi Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
serio_raw   Raw serio driver
mac80211    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
uvcvideo    USB Video Class driver
videodev    Device registrar for Video4Linux drivers v2
v4l2_compat_ioctl32 
snd Advanced Linux Sound Architecture driver for soundcards.
cfg80211    wireless configuration support
toshiba_acpi    Toshiba Laptop ACPI Extras Driver
sparse_keymap   Generic support for sparse keymaps
i915    Intel Graphics
wmi ACPI-WMI Mapping Driver
mac_hid 
soundcore   Core sound module
mei Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
snd_page_alloc  Memory allocator for ALSA system.
drm_kms_helper  DRM KMS helper
drm DRM shared core routines
i2c_algo_bit    I2C-Bus bit-banging algorithm
video   ACPI Video Driver
lp  
parport 
sdhci_pci   Secure Digital Host Controller Interface PCI driver
atl1c   Atheros 1000M Ethernet Network Driver
sdhci   Secure Digital Host Controller Interface core driver


Display

Display
Resolution  1366x768 pixels
Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Version 1.11.3
Monitors
Monitor 0   1366x768 pixels
Extensions
BIG-REQUESTS    
Composite   
DAMAGE  
DOUBLE-BUFFER   
DPMS    
DRI2    
GLX 
Generic Event Extension 
MIT-SCREEN-SAVER    
MIT-SHM 
RANDR   
RECORD  
RENDER  
SECURITY    
SGI-GLX 
SHAPE   
SYNC    
X-Resource  
XC-MISC 
XFIXES  
XFree86-DGA 
XFree86-VidModeExtension    
XINERAMA    
XInputExtension 
XKEYBOARD   
XTEST   
XVideo  
XVideo-MotionCompensation   
OpenGL
Vendor  Unknown
Renderer    Unknown
Version Unknown
Direct Rendering    No


Environment Variables
Environment Variables
GNOME_KEYRING_PID   1909
USER    newboldrob
LANGUAGE    en_CA:en
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE   ubuntu
HOME    /home/newboldrob
DESKTOP_SESSION ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE  498fb75b765154017de4d4f600000006-1337279911.793697-790372385
XDG_SEAT_PATH   /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL   /tmp/keyring-MbkTD5
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY    libappmenu.so
MANDATORY_PATH  /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
LOGNAME newboldrob
DEFAULTS_PATH   /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH    /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
XDG_SESSION_PATH    /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
DISPLAY :0
LANG    en_CA.UTF-8
XAUTHORITY  /home/newboldrob/.Xauthority
SHELL   /bin/bash
GDMSESSION  ubuntu
PWD /home/newboldrob
XDG_DATA_DIRS   /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   /tmp/keyring-MbkTD5/ssh
SSH_AGENT_PID   1956
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ljQIExwPFA,guid=ac9ec0861066e374d8f3adc9000001af
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID    this-is-deprecated
SESSION_MANAGER local/Satellite-E305:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1920,unix/Satellite-E305:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1920
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP Unity
GPG_AGENT_INFO  /tmp/keyring-MbkTD5/gpg:0:1
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE   /usr/share/applications/hardinfo.desktop
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID   3780

Devices

Processor
Processors
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz    1800.00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz    800.00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz    2301.00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz    800.00MHz


Memory
Memory
Total Memory    6060628 kB
Free Memory 3564244 kB
Buffers 59328 kB
Cached  897064 kB
Cached Swap 0 kB
Active  1593872 kB
Inactive    677628 kB
Active(anon)    1316576 kB
Inactive(anon)  299292 kB
Active(file)    277296 kB
Inactive(file)  378336 kB
Unevictable 92 kB
Mlocked 92 kB
Virtual Memory  6235132 kB
Free Virtual Memory 6235132 kB
Dirty   0 kB
Writeback   0 kB
AnonPages   1315308 kB
Mapped  170980 kB
Shmem   300700 kB
Slab    74044 kB
SReclaimable    42344 kB
SUnreclaim  31700 kB
KernelStack 3944 kB
PageTables  43348 kB
NFS_Unstable    0 kB
Bounce  0 kB
WritebackTmp    0 kB
CommitLimit 9265444 kB
Committed_AS    4603192 kB
VmallocTotal    34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed 564792 kB
VmallocChunk    34359169728 kB
HardwareCorrupted   0 kB
AnonHugePages   0 kB
HugePages_Total 0
HugePages_Free  0
HugePages_Rsvd  0
HugePages_Surp  0
Hugepagesize    2048 kB
DirectMap4k 55296 kB
DirectMap2M 6184960 kB


PCI Devices
PCI Devices
Host bridge Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
VGA compatible controller   Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Communication controller    Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
USB controller  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Audio device    Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
ISA bridge  Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
SATA controller Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
SMBus   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
USB controller  NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
USB Devices

Printers
Printers
No printers found   
Battery
Battery: BAT1
State   discharging (load: 1253 mA)
Capacity    3876 mAh / 6000 mAh (64.60%)
Battery Technology  rechargeable (LION)
Model Number    PA3921U-1BRS
Serial Number   
Sensors
Input Devices
Input Devices
Power Button    
Lid Switch  
Power Button    
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard    
Toshiba input device    
CNF9055 
Video Bus   
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad  
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm   3=
Storage
SCSI Disks
ATA Seagate ST950056    
MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8A0AS    
Generic- xD/SD/M.S. 
DMI
BIOS
Date    02/10/2012
Vendor  INSYDE
Version 2.20
Board
Name    Base Board Product Name
Vendor  Intel Corp. (www.intel.com)
Resources
I/O Ports
0000-0cf7   PCI Bus 0000:00
0000-001f   dma1
0020-0021   pic1
0040-0043   timer0
0050-0053   timer1
0060-0060   keyboard
0062-0062   EC data
0064-0064   keyboard
0066-0066   EC cmd
0070-0077   rtc0
0080-008f   dma page reg
00a0-00a1   pic2
00c0-00df   dma2
00f0-00ff   fpu
0400-0453   pnp 00:05
0400-0403   ACPI PM1a_EVT_BLK
0404-0405   ACPI PM1a_CNT_BLK
0408-040b   ACPI PM_TMR
0410-0415   ACPI CPU throttle
0420-042f   ACPI GPE0_BLK
0450-0450   ACPI PM2_CNT_BLK
0454-0457   pnp 00:07
0458-047f   pnp 00:05
0500-057f   pnp 00:05
0680-069f   pnp 00:05
0cf8-0cff   PCI conf1
0d00-ffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
1004-1013   pnp 00:05
164e-164f   pnp 00:05
2000-2fff   PCI Bus 0000:0a
2000-207f   Atheros Communications Inc. AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
2000-207f   Atheros 1000M Ethernet Network Driver
3000-3fff   PCI Bus 0000:03
4000-403f   Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
4040-405f   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
4060-407f   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
4060-407f   ahci
40a0-40a7   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
40a0-40a7   ahci
40c0-40c7   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
40c0-40c7   ahci
413c-413f   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
413c-413f   ahci
4154-4157   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
4154-4157   ahci
ffff-ffff   pnp 00:05
ffff-ffff   pnp 00:05


Memory
00000000-0000ffff   reserved
00010000-0009d7ff   System RAM
0009d800-0009ffff   reserved
000a0000-000bffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
000c0000-000cefff   Video ROM
000cf000-000cffff   Adapter ROM
000e0000-000fffff   reserved
000f0000-000fffff   System ROM
00100000-ace3efff   System RAM
01000000-016699ab   Kernel code
016699ac-01ce4fff   Kernel data
01dd3000-01f28fff   Kernel bss
ace3f000-acebefff   reserved
acebf000-acfbefff   ACPI Non-volatile Storage
acfbf000-acffefff   ACPI Tables
acfff000-acffffff   System RAM
ad000000-af9fffff   reserved
afa00000-feafffff   PCI Bus 0000:00
afa00000-afa00fff   pnp 00:0a
b0000000-bfffffff   Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
c0000000-c03fffff   Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
c0400000-c13fffff   PCI Bus 0000:03
c1400000-c14fffff   PCI Bus 0000:0a
c1400000-c143ffff   Atheros Communications Inc. AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
c1400000-c143ffff   Atheros 1000M Ethernet Network Driver
c1500000-c15fffff   PCI Bus 0000:09
c1500000-c1501fff   Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
c1500000-c1501fff   Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
c1600000-c25fffff   PCI Bus 0000:03
c1600000-c16000ff   Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
c1600000-c16000ff   mmc0
c1601000-c1601fff   Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
c1601000-c1601fff   Realtek PCI-Express card reader driver
c2600000-c26fffff   PCI Bus 0000:02
c2600000-c2601fff   NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
c2600000-c2601fff   xhci_hcd
c2700000-c2703fff   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
c2700000-c2703fff   ICH HD audio
c2704000-c270400f   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
c2704000-c270400f   Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
c2706000-c27060ff   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
c2708000-c27087ff   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
c2708000-c27087ff   ahci
c2709000-c27093ff   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
c2709000-c27093ff   ehci_hcd
c270a000-c270a3ff   Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
c270a000-c270a3ff   ehci_hcd
e0000000-efffffff   PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-ff]
e0000000-efffffff   reserved
e0000000-efffffff   pnp 00:0a
feb00000-feb03fff   reserved
fec00000-fec00fff   reserved
fec00000-fec003ff   IOAPIC 0
fed00000-fed003ff   HPET 0
fed10000-fed19fff   reserved
fed10000-fed17fff   pnp 00:0a
fed18000-fed18fff   pnp 00:0a
fed19000-fed19fff   pnp 00:0a
fed1c000-fed1ffff   reserved
fed1c000-fed1ffff   pnp 00:0a
fed20000-fed3ffff   pnp 00:0a
fed90000-fed93fff   pnp 00:0a
fee00000-fee00fff   Local APIC
fee00000-fee00fff   reserved
ffd80000-ffffffff   reserved
100000000-1cfdfffff System RAM
1cfe00000-1cfffffff RAM buffer
DMA
4   cascade
Network

Interfaces
Network Interfaces
lo  0.06MiB 0.06MiB 127.0.0.1
wlan0   3.85MiB 1.30MiB 192.168.0.2
eth0    0.00MiB 0.00MiB 

Benchmarks

CPU Blowfish
CPU Blowfish
This Machine    1800 MHz    4.303
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz (null)  26.1876862
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz) (null)  172.816713
CPU CryptoHash
CPU CryptoHash
This Machine    1800 MHz    327.916
CPU Fibonacci
CPU Fibonacci
This Machine    1800 MHz    1.874
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz (null)  8.1375674
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz) (null)  58.07682
CPU N-Queens
CPU N-Queens
This Machine    1800 MHz    5.493
FPU FFT
FPU FFT
This Machine    1800 MHz    1.092
FPU Raytracing
FPU Raytracing
This Machine    1800 MHz    3.930
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz (null)  40.8816714
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz) (null)  161.312647
```

Comment: Please post a screen shot of your current configuration.Since its a sensitive task we need to understand the structure very well. use `gparted` to get the drive map.

Answer (score 1):

According to my suggestion the most forward way would be New installation [Migration may cause some issues] on the desired drive and the Larger partitions which you want for storage can be reformatted [ if you want it windows recognizable also then FORMAT it in NTFS]  before new installation in same partitioning menu while Installation.

Don't worry about the working windows partition it would still get  recognized  , and as far as swap is concerned don't make any changes as it is considerably set.

Comment: I took this route as I had the installation CD handy and a bunch of spare time to make sure it all went well.

I think that there's a big chance I won't need as much room as I left (an 80GB Ubuntu Partition is way more than I need) but I'll figure out in time how much space I'll need and then maybe partition a new swap area.  Since it'll be closer to the outer rings of the HDD it'll be quicker.  Either that or just resize the storage partition.

Thanks for the dose of reality, tijybba.  This was easier than doing something I'd never done before to potentially mess something up.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dd` tool to make a image of your current partiton then copy that to the root of the other partition. for example:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sda2
```

If you wanted to copy `sda1` to `sda2`, for instance.

Comment: I was told 'permission denied' in the terminal.  I presume that's a command to input once I've made the image and migrated it.

Comment: you need to preceed the commands with sudo, or log in as root,                     if you want to, make a image first by using the of=NAME.img syntax then once you have the .img file, then copy it to the other parttion by using the img file in the if= syntax (ex. sudo dd if=name.img of=/dev/sdX(partiton you want to copy to)

Comment: from the screenshot, it looks like you will want to do something like this: first- sudo dd if=/dev/sda7 of=sda7.img  then - sudo dd if=sda7.img of=/dev/sda5